# Nasm - "real" randomness via uninitialized variables?

Tags: windows, assembly, random, initialization, nasm

I'm trying to build a number generator in `Nasm`. For this purpose I'd like to declare a few "variables" (I know Nasm only has labels, not variables) but not define them. The problem is when declaring variables in `.bss` they are automatically `null` initialized.

**My Question is:**
Is there a way to let the variables keep the values their reserved memory had, before they get `null` initialized?

The OS is Windows.

Comment: Even if you did that it is unlikely to be a particularly good random number.  Non-deterministic is not the same as "random".

Comment: If you need random number you should use a random number generator. :)

Answer (score 6):

No.  For security reasons, the operating system clears all memory pages it maps into your process.

Consider using the `rdrand` instruction if you have a sufficiently new processor. Alternatively, use the [CryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) function from the Win32 API.